# Compiling 32 bit libGLEW.so on 64 bit linux

Tags: compiler-errors, 32bit-64bit, glew

I'm trying to build a 32 bit libGLEW.so.. I'm on 64 bit linux.. I've tried adding -m32 to the CFLAGS in the Makefile.. Which says:

```
cc -DGLEW_NO_GLU -O2 -Wall -W -Iinclude  -m32 -fPIC  -o tmp/linux/default/shared/glew.o -c src/glew.c
cc -shared -Wl,-soname=libGLEW.so.1.9 -o lib/libGLEW.so.1.9.0 tmp/linux/default/shared/glew.o -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -L/usr/lib64 -lXmu -lXi -lGL -lXext -lX11 
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `tmp/linux/default/shared/glew.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: tmp/linux/default/shared/glew.o: file class ELFCLASS32 incompatible with ELFCLASS64
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: File in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [lib/libGLEW.so.1.9.0] Error 1
```

I'm not exactly sure what it means? Seems like its building a 32 bit .o file, but trying to link it as a 64 target? How do I fix this.. I've seen it adds the -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 and -L/usr/lib64 , but I've also tried running make SYSTEM=gnu which ads the /usr/X11R6/lib and /usr/lib folders instead, but its giving me the same error..

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I needed the packages listed below. I added -m32 to both CFLAGS and LDFLAGS in the Makefiles and just to be sure I set -m32 to CFLAGS, CXXFLAGS and LDFLAGS in the environement just to be sure.. and then ran make

```
libx11-dev:i386
libxext-dev:i386
libxmu-dev:i386
libxi-dev:i386
libgl1-mesa-dev:i386

export CFLAGS='-m32'
export CXXFLAGS='-m32'
export LDFLAGS='-m32'
make
```